# Sharing code and assets between Play 2.4 services?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a number of projects in Play 2.4 that will require sharing code and assets (css, js) mostly to stop the assets getting out of synk with one another.

I come from a, mostly, C# environment using ServiceStack in which bundleing shared files was as easy as setting up a new DLL project and have it hold the CSS and JS that you wish to share.

I know you are able to create "modules" in play but, A) The documentation isnt hugely clear on how to achieve this, and B) AFAIK this is just for sharing Java/Scala classes/code, can modules contain Views, Controllers, and static files?

At the moment I have a repository containing the core of a service and then a submodule that contains the shared files and code, and then symlink the files in the submodule to their respective location in the main service. This works but is much uglier than I would like!

Comment: Hi @RichyHBM. Did you get a solution that you're pleased with? For CSS and JS I'd consider WebJars (which Play now supports). Personally, I am looking into ways to do this whole modularity (including static assets), via maven (i.e. native sbt dependencies). Will be open sources maybe in Jan 2016. Tell me 1-on-1 if you are interested to collaborate / get notified?